# Maya Python Object 'columnLayout' not found

Tags: python, runtime-error, maya

I'm creating a simple tool in Python for Maya with 2 tabs.
My problem is when I put the UI in the function myWindowUI, Maya give me error.

Can anyone help me to fix it? I'm very new with Python.

Thank you very much for your time!

```
def myWindowUI():
    
    winName = 'My Window'
    tabs = cmds.tabLayout()
    
    if cmds.window(winName, exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI(winName)
        
    cmds.window(winName, widthHeight=(300, 300), sizeable=False)
          
    def renamerUI():
        renamerUI.fTab = cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
        cmds.text('Select & Rename')
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2,)
        cmds.button(label='Static Mesh')
        cmds.button(label='Spline')
    
        cmds.setParent('..')
        cmds.separator(height=20)
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2, adjustableColumn=1)
        cmds.textField()
        cmds.button(label='Rename')
        cmds.setParent('..')
        cmds.setParent('..')
    
    renamerUI()
        
    def poserUI():
        poserUI.sTab = cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
        cmds.button(label='pose')
        cmds.button(label='pose02')
        cmds.setParent('..')
        
    poserUI()
    print('working')    
    cmds.tabLayout(tabs, edit=True, tabLabel=((renamerUI.fTab, 'Renamer'),(poserUI.sTab, 'Poser')))
        
    cmds.showWindow()
    

myWindowUI()
```

This is the Maya error:

```
# Error: Object 'My_Window|columnLayout2120' not found.
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 42, in <module>
#   File "<maya console>", line 37, in myWindowUI
# RuntimeError: Object 'My_Window|columnLayout2120' not found. #
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the solution, I just moved the tabs = cmds.tabLayout() after cmds.window and worked.
I guess because the deleteUI deleted the tabLayout as well?